# Python: TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Tags: python, csv

I am reading CSV using python, here is the code.

```
train_csv = open('train.csv')
test_csv = open('test.csv')
train_data_reader = csv.DictReader(train_csv)
test_data_reader = csv.DictReader(test_csv)

row=[]
for row in train_data_reader:
    X.append([int(item) for item in row[4:]]) 
    char = row[1]
    Y.append(charIntConversion(char))
    train_id.append(row[0])
    prediction.append(row[1])
for row in test_data_reader:
    test_id.append(row[0])
    test_X.append([int(item) for item in row[4:]]
```

when I tried to run the code, it shows that TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' for

```
X.append([int(item) for item in row[4:]])
test_X.append([int(item) for item in row[4:]]
```

X and test_X should contain the value from column 4 to last column of the CSV.

May I know what's wrong with my code and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Are you sure `row` is a list? It seems like it might be a dictionary. Indeed given that you specifically use the DictReader, it's not at all clear why you'd think otherwise.

Comment: I am using DictReader because I want to skip the first row. but I did not realise that it is a dictionary not list.I have modified my code and solve this problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

I can see you have resolved your issue, but I thought I'd leave an answer here for any future readers. Who might get caught by this (I just was).

The issue is that the object is a dictionary and you are trying to pass it a slice, which is not hashable and hence cant be used as a dict key.

Simple example

```
>>> d = {0: 5, 1: 6, 2: 7, 3: 8, 4: 9}
>>> d[:5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

What you are trying to do is take `n` items from the collection. So the way to achieve this is to first convert the dict to a list (which is sliceable). To do this use `dict.items`, `dict.keys` or `dict.values` depending on your use case.

A dict (recent python 3.6 development notwithstanding) is not ordered and so what you will get back from `dict.items` (or friends) may not be in an order useful to you. So you can sort it before making the slice.

```
>>> sorted(d.items())[:5]
[(0, 5), (1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9)]
```

The above code is slightly ugly, but works.

You could avoid the indexing by using `islice` from itertools

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> list(islice(sorted(d.items()), 5))
[(0, 5), (1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9)]
```

You'd provide a key to sort if the default sorting order was not what you wanted. This way is inefficient as it sorts the entire collection before slicing, not sure of a way around that though.

Anyone arriving at this page and being puzzled by the above error, will not have realised they are attempting a slice on a dictionary. Performing a slice on a dictionary, doesn't really make a lot of sense and most experienced developers would realise that if you do that you are asking for an unpredictable result.

If you genuinely do want to take the first n elements from a dictionary, say a row from a csv file where the columns are in some prescribed order. It would be much better to format the required keys into a tuple and just take those elements from the dict.

e.g.

To take only the first two columns from the dict

```
people = [{'name': 'paul', 'job': 'programmer', 'age': 'old'}, 
          {'name': 'chris', 'job': 'student', 'age': 'young'}]

>>> for p in people:
...     res = [p[key] for key in ('name', 'job')]
...     print(res)
['paul', 'programmer']
['chris', 'student']
```

hth

Answer (score 0):

## Encoder Example for Multiple Linear Regression Model

```
# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:4].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,4].values

# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 3] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 3])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [3])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```