# How to slice a Python List Item?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I tried this code in Python:

```
listepositive = soup.findAll('span', attrs{'class':'search_review_summary'})

pos = listpositive[0][3:5]

print(pos)
```

to get listpositive list 0 char 3 to 5.
Got TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'...?!

Can you please give me a hint?

Comment: You did not get a list back neither did you get a string. You very likely got `None` and that is why you cannot slice it. But an example of an unhashable datatype set would be a dictionary,  but since `findAll()` in `bs4` returns a list, then odd are you are getting back a value of None.

Comment: What does `print(listpositive)` give you?

Comment: possibly you need to make a list from findall method, because it returns an object ```list(soup.findAll(...))```

Comment: there is already an answer exist on such case : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885488/python-typeerror-unhashable-type-slice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked for me:

```
listpositive = soup.findAll('div', class_='row')
if listpositive is not None and len(listpositive) >= 0:
  pos = listpositive[0]
  print(str(pos)[3:5])
else:
  print('could not find any elements')
```

listpositive is of type `ResultSet` and is not a `list`.
From what I understand, you would like to get the characters 3 to 5 from the first element of the Result Set, and the above code does just that.

I'm grabbing the first element of the result set, converting it to a string and then slicing it to get the 3rd to 5th characters.

Comment: Thank you! You understand right! But is this best practice to get the characters?

Comment: If you're just trying to get a substring of the content of a tag (while ignoring all the tag attributes), then you should really be using ```.contents```
Here's more information on it https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children

Answer (score 2):

import numpy as np

```
  #pos = listpositive[0,2:6] you can do this if listpositive is already a numpy array
    newpos = np.array([listpositive])
    newpos[0,2:6]
```

install numpy if you dont have and you are okay

Comment: seems a bit of an over-kill installing `numpy` and all for something that could be just casted to a list...

Comment: what's the need for ```numpy```?